# Appending class to TD tag based on specific arguments and innerHTML of including A tag by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

It's a little bit tricky and I'm looking for a good JavaScript-Solution without modifying it's own source.

The jQueryUI datepicker widget is composing a month control with is looking like this in HTML:

```
<div id="mjcEvents_pJuiCalendar"><div class="UC_JuiCalendar Panel datepicker hasDatepicker"><div class="ui-datepicker-inline ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" style="display: block;">
<div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"><a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all" data-handler="prev" data-event="click" title="Prev"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span></a><div class="ui-datepicker-title"><span class="ui-datepicker-month">Juni-Events</span>&nbsp;<span class="ui-datepicker-year">2013</span></div>
</div>
<table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="ui-datepicker-week-col">W</th>
            <th><span title="Monday">M</span></th>
            <th><span title="Tuesday">D</span></th>
            <th><span title="Wednesday">M</span></th>
            <th><span title="Thursday">D</span></th>
            <th><span title="Friday">F</span></th>
            <th class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Saturday">S</span></th>
            <th class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Sunday">S</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="ui-datepicker-week-col">22</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">27</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">28</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">29</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">30</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">31</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end  ui-datepicker-today" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2013"><a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight" href="#">1</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-days-cell-over  ui-datepicker-current-day" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2013"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">2</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ui-datepicker-week-col">23</td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2013"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">3</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2013"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">4</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2013"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">5</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2013"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">6</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2013"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">7</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2013"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">8</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2013"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">9</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ui-datepicker-week-col">24</td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2013"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">10</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2013"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">11</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2013"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">12</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2013"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">13</a></td>
            <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2013"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">14</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2013"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">15</a></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">16</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ui-datepicker-week-col">25</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">17</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">18</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">19</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">20</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">21</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">22</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">23</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ui-datepicker-week-col">26</td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">24</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">25</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">26</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">27</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">28</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">29</span></td>
            <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">30</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I want to access specific TD tags by providing the dates, it should skip cases of other months as fast as it can, so it will be called several times (equals day cases) everytime I change the month.

All important TD tags has an A tag including. Others can be ignored since they are outside of the specific month.

So I need a function `markEvent(parentSelector, year, month, day)` ie. `markEvent($('#mjcEvents_pJuiCalendar'), 2013, 5, 7);` that will be append a new class like `isEvent` to the TD tag of `<td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2013"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">7</a></td>`. As you see it's pretty fine to use jQuery in my case.

Thanks for advice.

Comment: try to use classes as much as possible, then you can `$('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');` and then `$('.monthClass.dayClass.yearClass').addClass('highlithed');`

Comment: but I can't, that's the point. The HTML that is shown here is generated by jQueryUI, so I must read it's `data-*` arguments with JS. Adding the class itself is pretty easy. So, do you know how I can this accomplish this?

Comment: so... `$('td[data-month=5][data-year=2013]').each(function(){markIfContainsDate(this,7);});` and something `if($(this).child('a').html()==7){$(this).addClass('highlighted');}`?

Comment: yea, this looks good, I'm going to test it out and response soon. Thanks.